# Keep columns in join data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table

I do not get why in this join I can not retrieve the column sub_item of my DT2?

```
DT <- data.table(ID=c(1:4),OBS_VALUE=10:13)
DT2 <- data.table(ID=c(1:4),sum_item=c(10,11.5,12.5,18))

setkey(DT,ID)
setkey(DT2,ID)

S_toset_sum <- DT[DT2,diff := abs(OBS_VALUE-sum_item)][diff<3]
```

in the output I would like to have still sum_item as I want to keep this column instead of the OBS_VALUE column.

Comment: `sum_item` belongs to `DT2` while you took `DT` + a new column which you've created (`diff`), why would `sum_item` be there?

Comment: Return a list in the j argument containing the variables that you want to return. For example, `DT[DT2, on="ID", .(sum_item, diff = abs(OBS_VALUE-sum_item))][diff<3]`.

Comment: Maybe a more data.table-ish way: ```DT[DT2, `:=` (sum_item = i.sum_item, diff = abs(OBS_VALUE-sum_item))][diff<3]```

Comment: If your two tables have the same key (in the sense that there's one ID == 1, one ID == 2, etc), it's not clear why they are separate to begin with...

Comment: Frank, I think that's a strange thing to say without understanding how large these tables are, what the values actually represent, how the tables are created, etc.  Of course it would be better if all of the data resided in a huge mega table, but that's not always practical.

Comment: @lmo wow, you learn something new about data.table every day. thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the columns you wish to keep, as well as the key you wish to join on.

```
S_toset_sum <- DT[DT2, on = 'ID', .(ID, OBS_VALUE, sum_item, diff = abs(OBS_VALUE-sum_item))][diff<3]
```